# Extract values from array

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, eventsource

Hello my script watches a stream...

On a message it will extract some data for me using a variable.

Here's the script:

```
  var evtSource = new EventSource("http://URL.com/_watch//_index?_=1557958948927");

evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
var obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
var lineString = JSON.stringify(obj.line)
var size = JSON.stringify(obj.lineWidth)
var color = JSON.stringify(obj.lineColor) // Not needed, but defined anyways.
var chat = JSON.stringify(obj.msg)
var line = obj.line
console.log(line)

line.forEach(function(point, index){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(point)); // console log example// -> "[120,250]"
  });
}
```

in google's console it logs something like this [120,250]

How could I get each number, like the 120 as a variable, and the 250 as a different variable?

I tried something with the substr() method but it didn't work. It would somehow get the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't stringify the `point` array. Without stringifying you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the array, like this:

```
const [x, y] = point;
```

or in a traditional way:

```
const x = point[0];
const y = point[1];
```

both solutions are equal and produce the same output. Example:

```js
const point = [120, 250];

const [x, y] = point;

console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y}`);
```

So your `.forEach()` could look like this:

```
line.forEach(function(point, index){
    const [x, y] = point;
    console.log(x, y); // console log example// -> "120 250"
});
```

Comment: thank you. this works. i will accept when it lets me, it said in 6 minutes.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help ;)